# Ruby on rails how control date of a resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, controller, controls

My promotions have a sell-by date(expiration date),
How can destroy it when date expiration?? I think to control the date with `Date.today.to_s` because return in this form `"YYYY-MM-DD"` the date like in my DB.

But I have the controller show and destroy where I put this?

```
   def show
@promotion = Promotion.find(params[:id])

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @promotion }
end
end

     def destroy
@promotion = Promotion.find(params[:id])
if @promotion.user == current_user #if user is the owner of that promotion
  @promotion.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to promotions_url, notice:'Promotion was successfully delete.' }
    format.json { head :ok }
  end
else
  redirect_to root_path ,:alert => 'This is not your promotion, you can delete only those who have entered.'
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should play with cron job

I have application and using `clockwork gem` for handle `scheduled application tasks`

You could usage clockwork gem in [here](https://github.com/tomykaira/clockwork#Quickstart)

### Example

---

**First** put into your gemfile

```
gem 'clockwork'
gem 'foreman'
```

run `bundle install`

**Second** create `yourapp/app/clock.rb`

```
require './config/boot'
require './config/environment'
require 'clockwork'

module Clockwork
 # every one day at midnight cron schedule 

 every(1.day, 'promo.expired', :at => '00:00') {

   # find all promotion with codition :expiration_date equal to date today
   # if :expiration_date with type Date

   @promotions = Promotion.all(:conditions => { :expiration_date = DateTime.now.to_date })   
   @promotions.each do |promo|
     # destroy promo
     promo.destroy
   end
 }
end
```

Third, let's test

```
clockworkd -c clock.rb start
```

If success, you could using `foreman start` for every start application with run schedule

[Here's screencasts for foreman](http://railscasts.com/episodes/281-foreman?view=asciicast)

Hope this help.